# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{': What could be wrong?

Tags: wordpress, user-registration

I'm currently working on a registration form for my wordpress site. I got this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\WoodClef\wp-content\themes\woodclef\inc\custormregform.php
>   on line 14

Here are the codes:

```
echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
    foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ) {
       // Exclude default roles such as administrator etc. Add your own
       if ( ! in_array( $value['name'], [ 'Administrator', 'Contributor', ] ) {
          echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
       }
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Line 14 here is

```
if ( ! in_array( $value['name'], [ 'Administrator', 'Contributor', ] ) {
```

If I should remove the if statement, it works but I don't want to remove it.

Here is the whole code:

```
<?php

// How To create User Registration Form

//1. Add a new form element...
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

    global $wp_roles;

    echo '<select name="role" class="input">';
    foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ) {
       // Exclude default roles such as administrator etc. Add your own
       if ( ! in_array( $value['name'], [ 'Administrator', 'Contributor', ] ) {
          echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
       }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}

//2. Add validation.
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['role'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['role'] ) && trim( $_POST['role'] ) == '' ) {
         $errors->add( 'role_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a role.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {

   $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => $_POST['role'] ) );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( ! in_array( $value['name'], [ 'Administrator', 'Contributor', ] ) {
```

I believe you're missing a ')'... does this look better?

```
if ( ! in_array( $value['name'], [ 'Administrator', 'Contributor', ] ) ) {
```

where there's one ')' to close the if and one to close the "in_array" function.

Comment: Thank you so much. Wondered how I miss this!